# simple Wordpress If/Else

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, if-statement, wordpress-featured-image

I have two different methods for displaying Wordpress Thumbnails

What I would like to do is, display the first method, and if it is not available then to display thumbs using the second method.

Below are the Two Methods for displaying Post Thumbnails.

**Method 1**

```
<!--Begin WordPress Featured post thumbnail-->
<div class="postthumbcon">
<?php
// check if the post has a featured image assigned to it.
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
// get the src of the large size featured image
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );
$thumbnailSrc = $src[0];
// output image resized with timthumb
?>
<div class="postthumb">
">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnailSrc; ?>&h=125&w=165" alt="">

</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<!--end WordPress Featured post thumbnail-->
```

**Here is the second method.**

```
<!--Begin Timthumb thumbnail-->
<?php // This will show the image and link the image to the post. Alter the width and height (in both places) to your needs. ?>

<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ) { ?>
<div class="postthumb">
" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumb", $single = true); ?>&h=150&w=150&zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="150" height="150" />
</div>
<?php } ?>

<!--End Timthumb thumbnail-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="postthumbcon">
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    // method one
} else if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ) {
    // Method two
} 
?>
</div>
```

This will see if the post has a thumbnail, which you were already doing, but if it doesn't exist it will run the `else` clause meaning the second if statement will run only if the first fails.

Also, you appear to have the first part of what I am guessing to be a link in method two, see this line:

```
" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumb", $single = true); ?>&h=150&w=150&zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="150" height="150" />
```

Here's how your code could look in full:

```
<div class="postthumbcon">
    <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'large' );
        $thumbnailSrc = $src[0];
    ?>
        <div class="postthumb">
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumbnailSrc; ?>&h=125&w=165" alt="" />
        </div>
    <?php } else if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true) ) { ?>
        <div class="postthumb">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "thumb", $single = true); ?>&h=150&w=150&zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="150" height="150" />
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, you should accept the answer so other people can see it's solved :)